# Mocking repository with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, moq

I'm using mog for mocking a repository with LINQ to SQL like this:

```
public static IProductsRepository MockProductsRepository(params Product[] prods){
    // Generate an implementer of IProductsRepository at runtime using Moq
    var mockProductsRepos = new Mock<IProductsRepository>();
    mockProductsRepos.Setup(x => x.Products).Returns(prods.AsQueryable());
    return mockProductsRepos.Object;
}

public interface IProductsRepository{
    IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
    void SaveProduct(Product product);
    void DeleteProduct(Product product);
}
```

How can I change this function for the Entity framework if I am using it like this:

```
public interface IProductsRepository : IEntities{
    EntityState GetEntryState(object entry);
    void SetEntryState(object entry, EntityState state);
    void Commit();
}

public interface IEntities{
    DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am using `DbSet`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Since `IProductsRepository` implements `IEntities` you should have a

```
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

property in there, but what I would do is add a `Fetch` method to `IProductRepository` like

```
public interface IProductsRepository : IEntities
{
    EntityState GetEntryState(object entry);
    void SetEntryState(object entry, EntityState state);
    void Commit();

    // New method
    IQueryable<Product> FetchAll();
}
```

Then, in your `MockProductsRepository` change the setup line as follows:

```
mockProductsRepos.Setup(x => x.FetchAll()).Returns(prods.AsQueryable());
```